# Ubuntu 19.04 dynamic dock not working

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, 19.04

Had 18.10 before upgraded and I had dynamic dock.
Now my dynamic dock doesnt work anymore, it stay black any way.

This is my screen on dynamic mode, my dock just stays black at every screen I switch:

[image]

Tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode 'DYNAMIC'
```

and tried changing with the tweak-tool to dynamic, didn't help too.

Comment: https://ibb.co/HK71Kxk this  is my screen on dynamic mode, my dock just stays black at every screen I switch.

Comment: still didnt find any solution

Comment: Yes I am using dash to dock, and have no errors.

Comment: See if this is useful: [How to make dock background 80% transparent in Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136263/how-to-make-dock-background-80-transparent-in-ubuntu-19-04)

Answer (score -1):

The devs disabled it for now but I believe they are planning to re-enable it in future

There is a Dynamic Panel Transparency GNOME extension you can get to enable it, which can be installed from the Ubuntu Software app.

Source: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/04/how-to-re-enable-dynamic-transparency-on-the-ubuntu-19-04-desktop

Comment: The question is about the dynamic transparency feature of the *dock* (the bar at the left of the screen as per [OP's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n97O.jpg)), I believe what you're talking about is the dynamic transparency of the *top* bar or panel (as per [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/gnome-shell-translucent-top-panel-effect-removed)). Two different things.