# Ubuntu dock goes white whenever I install or remove a package

Tags: dock

Whenever I run:

```
sudo apt remove
```

Or:

```
sudo apt install
```

The background of the Ubuntu Dock turns white
and remains that way until I restart the computer.

[image: it just turns white]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Some of the items [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1136390/1222991) may help resolve the issue. Be sure to look at [Suzana’s comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136263/how-to-make-dock-background-80-transparent-in-ubuntu-19-04#comment2377822_1136390) with regards to the colour 

Comment: I am running the 20.04.3 LTS version